# ASP.NET VNext Request.Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous MVC version i use authentication service like this

```
public class OvAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute
    {
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {
                ..........

                var user = await ContainerFactory.Container.GetInstance<IMembershipService>().GetUser(token);
                if (user == null)
                      ........

                actionContext.Request.Properties["User"] = user;
            }
   }



    [OvAuthorize]
    public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        public User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return Request.Properties["User"] as User; //ERROR
            }
        }
    }
```

But now, i can't access Request.Properties in new Controller definition

Answer (score 2):

You can get `User` directly from the `Controller` instance.  The following property is exposed on [Controller](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L202-L211).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for user associated with the executing action.
/// </summary>
public ClaimsPrincipal User
{
    get
    {
        return Context?.User;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but now, Identity Framework looks like piece of sh... and i don't want to use it in my small project

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO What are you talking about? Identity Framework? That's a property on the controller... If you want a custom object, you can create a custom property and map the `ClaimsIdentity` to your needs.